# Review a simple sprite sheet animation script

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is just a simple script for testing sprite sheet animations. I'm trying to improve my code style, so I'm curious about suggestions anyone might have about best practices or readability.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //just a shim to provide requestAnimationFrame support in different browsers
            if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
              window.requestAnimationFrame = (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              function (callback) {
                                                return window.setTimeout(callback, 17 /*~ 1000/60*/);
                                              });
            }

            if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
              window.cancelAnimationFrame = (window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                             window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                             window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                             window.msCancelAnimationFrame || window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                             window.oCancelAnimationFrame || window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                             window.clearTimeout);
            }

            //loads when the body element has loaded.
            var init = function() {

                //the actual event loop. Runs inside of the init() closure.
                var animate = function() {
                    (function animloop(){
                        //clear the canvas
                        canvas.width = canvas.width;

                        //increment the tick variable.
                        tick++;

                        //if it's greater than five, reset to zero and go to the next tile
                        if (tick > 5) { 
                            tick = 0;

                            //check to see if currently viewing the last tile in the sequence. If so, reset to the first, otherwise go the the net one.
                            if (currentTile > tiles - 2) {
                                currentTile = 0;
                            } else {
                                currentTile++
                            }
                        }

                        //pull the current tile out of the sprite sheet and draw it to the canvas.
                        ctx.drawImage(img, currentTile * tileWidth, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight, 0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);

                        //let the browser decide when to call the event loop again
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
                    })();
                };

                //get a reference to the canvas element
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

                //same for the canvas context
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                //and index that refers to the tile currently selected
                var currentTile = 0;

                //used in the event loop to slow down the animation
                var tick = 0;

                //*************************************
                //change this next value depending on the number of tiles in the animation
                var tiles = 5;

                //used to select the tile currently being drawn from sprite sheet
                var tileWidth = null;

                //same
                var tileHeight = null;

                //new image object
                img = new Image();

                //called when the image loads
                img.onload = function() {

                    //the sprite sheet should be composed of tiles of equal length and the animation should be centered on each tile.
                    tileWidth = img.width / tiles;

                    //the script only handles sprite sheets that are one dimensional. 
                    //ie, the animation should only run along the x axis, so the animation will always be the same height as the image itself.
                    tileHeight = img.height;

                    //call the event loop
                    animate();
                };

                //*********************************
                //this is the name of the file you want to test. Make sure it's in the
                //the same directory as the script
                //load the specified sprite sheet
                img.src = 'zombieChase3.png';



            };

        </script>
    </head>

    //run init when body is loaded
    <body onload="init()">

        //just a canvas element
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        You need a browser that supports the canvas element.
        </canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//I suggest you use this polyfill for the rAF and cAF
//https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671


//Enclosing the module in a closure to avoid pollution of the global scope
(function (exports) {

  //Let's make each sprite an object, so that we have a reusable constructor
  function Sprite(config) {

    //A typical convention to not lose the context is to store it in another variable
    var self = this;

    //Setting a few configs for this object
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.path = config.path;
    this.tiles = config.tiles;

    //We can add properties to the Sprite instance, like states and counters
    this.paused = false;
    this.tick = 0;

    //Let's load up the image when creating an instance
    var image = this.image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {

      //When loaded, get the info
      self.width = image.width;
      self.height = image.height;

      //Start the animation via the instance's start method
      self.animate();

    }
    image.src = this.path;
  }

  //Let's extend the constructor to have methods

  //Unpauses the instance and runs animate
  Sprite.prototype.play = function () {
    this.paused = false;
    this.animate();
  }

  //Our animation loop function
  Sprite.prototype.animate = function () {

    //If say the state is paused, don't request the next frame
    //Otherwise, schedule the next frame
    if(this.paused) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    //clear and draw
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;
    this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.tick * this.width, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    //reset it tiles reached
    if(++this.tick > this.tiles) this.tiles = 0;

  }

  //This one stops the animation
  Sprite.prototype.stop() {
    this.paused = true;
  }

  exports.load = function (config) {
    return new Sprite(config)
  }

}(this.Sprite = this.Sprite || {}));

//Extensibility. Don't limit yourself to a fixed set of configurations.
//Make your code reusable.
var sprite = Sprite.load({
  canvasId: 'canvas',
  path: 'zombieChase3.png',
  tiles: '5'
});

//you can control the sprite
sprite.play();
sprite.stop();

//Additionally, you can add something like play, pause, unload etc. which I just did
//Also, sprite sheets are usually big sheets containing more than one sequence per image
//you should consider that. If you Google "sprite sheets", you'll see.
```

Comment: +1 but only because the review is in the comments. I would be an even better post if you elaborated a little bit in plain text.